# Остановить выполнение setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Как при нажатии на кнопку остановить выполнение функции moveAndHide, в которой элемент сдвигается, а через 2 секунды исчезает, и вернуть элемент в начальное состояние?

```
fadeOut: function (element, duration) {
            element.style.transitionDuration = `${duration}ms`;
            element.classList.add('hide');
            element.classList.remove('show');
        },

moveAndHide: function (element, duration) {
            element.style.transitionDuration = `${duration / 5 * 2}ms`;
            element.style.transform = getTransform({x: 100, y: 20});
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                animaster().fadeOut(element, duration / 5 * 3)
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Написанная мной функция возвращает элемент на место, но скрытие элемента не прекращается до тех пор, пока не нажать на кнопку снова, но уже когда начнется скрытие.

```
function resetMoveAndHide(element) {
    element.style.transitionDuration = null;
    element.style.transform = getTransform({x: 0, y: 0});
    element.classList.add('show');
    element.classList.remove('hide');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myFunction = function() { console.log('foo') };

// устанавливаем таймер
let timer = setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
// удаляем таймер
clearTimeout(timer);
```